# Switch languages ubuntu 20.04 lxqt desktop

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, input-language

I wonder if anyone can please help me.

I have installed ubuntu 20.04. then installed the lxqt desktop for it.

I want to have two langues available for typing. And I want to switch between them by using 'alt space' or something similar.

I have not been able to do this. Can anyone please help?

I have been to keyboard layout and added second language. And chose alt space to change layout.

But it doesn't work.

Also, additional problem. I change keyboard model under keyboard and mouse settings. 'apply' then 'close'. Restart computer and the keyboard model has been lost and returns to basic 105 key. Could there be a bug in the keyboard layout settings?

Can anyone please help. Thanks

Comment: If it's Lubuntu you are using, you should check out the Fcitx preferences. See [this docs page](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.1/fcitx.html).

Answer (score 0):

Solution posted here: https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-19-10-lxqt-cannot-change-keyboard-layout-shortcuts-not-working/507/1

To tell a long story short

1. Add or remove keyboard layout
2. Set new shortcut for switching languages and/or set keyboard model
3. Press apply

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same. I had to remove fcitx which comes pre-loaded on 20.04. It seems to override "Keyboard Layout," so you need to get rid of it (as LXQt recommends). Then go to `Preferences --> LXQt Settings --> Keyboard and Mouse`. You should then be able to add your alphabet of choice.

Comment: I want to change the general gui language to german of Lubuntu 20_04. Can you give a hint to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can us <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> from keyboard to switch languages.